# What is on the mirror in Lorenzo's oil?

Tags: plot-explanation, lorenzos-oil

In the movie Lorenzo's Oil, Mckaela Odone has a quote taped on her mirror, but it is in small font and difficult to see. What is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The poem is "*[It Takes a Lifetime](http://webspace.webring.com/people/pq/quikkfastt/Lifetime.html)*" by Ruth Moyer Gilmour

> **IT TAKES A LIFETIME**
>
> IT TAKES A LIFETIME TO LEARN HOW TO LIVE, HOW TO SHARE AND HOW TO
>   GIVE.
>
> HOW TO FACE TRAGEDY THAT COMES YOUR WAY, HOW TO FIND COURAGE TO FACE
>   EACH NEW DAY.
>
> HOW TO SMILE WHEN YOUR HEART IS SORE, HOW TO GO ON WHEN YOU CAN TAKE
>   NO MORE.
>
> HOW TO LAUGH WHEN YOU WANT TO CRY, HOW TO BE BRAVE WHEN YOU SAY
>   GOODBYE.
>
> HOW TO STILL LOVE WHEN YOUR LOSS IS SO GREAT, HOW TO FORGIVE WHEN YOUR
>   URGE IS TO HATE.
>
> HOW TO BE SURE THAT GOD'S REALLY THERE, HOW TO FIND HIM, SEEK HIM IN
>   PRAYER.

[image]